# Android espresso test multiple fragments consecutively, inside the same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, testing, android-espresso

I have a fragment initially inside my activity, this fragment contains a button that's when it's clicked it open the second fragment, and the second  fragment contains a button that's when it's clicked it open the third fragment, and so on ...

Now I want to test the launch of the third fragment after passing by the 2 old fragment (not testing the fragment in isolation), I tried to preform a click in the button inside each fragment but it seems espresso doesn't wait for the 2 fragment to launch, before clicking the button inside it, is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code its hard to tell what the best way to handle this would be.

However this seems like an issue with the IdlingResource.  Espresso should wait until 2nd fragment has finished launching before moving forward.

You can handle it by adding a `SystemClock.sleep(int milliseconds)` . That is not an ideal solution however and sleeps should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a timing issue I have an Activity with 3 fragments all of which are visible concurrently. Android Espresso will only do tests in the top fragment and refuses to acknowledge the presence of all the rest of the fragments.